# Go through a list until some condition is met, in F#

Tags: f#

let's take this data:

```
let a = [10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 0; 15; 16]
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
[
    let mutable skip = false
    for i in 0 .. a.Length - 1 do
        if a.[i] = 0 then skip <- true
        if not skip then yield a.[i]
]
```

but I was wondering if List.unfold could be used for this? (and how?)

In practice, I'm getting a sequence of sequences (seq of rows, each holding a seq of columns, from an Excel file), and I want to stop the parsing when I encounter an empty line, but the simplified example illustrates it.

The expression above works, so this is about me learning if unfold could be applied to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `List.unfold`:

```
let a = [10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 0; 15; 16]
a
|> List.unfold (function
    | [] -> None
    | x :: rest -> if x = 0 then None else Some (x, rest)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use takeWhile:

```
let a = [10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 0; 15; 16]
Seq.takeWhile ((<>) 0) a
// |>  do your parsing
```

Comment: This works, but I was writing in the question that I'm trying to see specifically if unfold could work in this scenario. But thanks for the answer